# How to run a Node.js like a cron job?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I had a php file which made a REST API call to a url which returned a json object.

I converted the code to Node.js as show below which works like a charm. However, i ran a cron job for my php script to run every 5 minute.

I am not sure how a node js would work in this case ? Can i make node javascript file to run every 5 minutes without a cron ? The idea is to save the JSON object into a MySQL db from node.js

Can someone help me with the architecture here ? I am trying to understand how do i run a node.js file every 5 minutes ? Any tutorial or example would be great! Thanks in advance

I just started using node so i am very new to it

```
var http = require("http");
    url1 = "http://xyz.net/v2/plan/"


var request = http.get(url1, function (response) {   
    var buffer = "", 
        data,
        route;

    response.on("data", function (chunk) {
        buffer += chunk;
    }); 

    response.on("end", function (err) {
        console.log(buffer);
        console.log("\n");
        data = JSON.parse(buffer);
        // MYSQL code here to insert the object into Database every 5 minutes
    }); 
});
```

Comment: have you looked at node timers? http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html

Comment: https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron?

Comment: @Thanks Andy cron module worked for me !